# Rails 4.2: Retrieve Files without Extension ( collection_check_box )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, actionview, actionviewhelper

I have a list of pdf files passed through and displayed by Rails `collection_check_box` method...

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :upload_ids, Upload.where(file_type: ".pdf"), :id, :file_name do |b| %>
    <%= b.label do %>
    <%= b.check_box + b.text %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

How could I show the file name without the extension within this block of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract it manually :

```
<%= b.check_box + File.basename(b.text,'.*') %>
```